# How to iterate inner array of the object in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.radiolabels={
                Name:"",
                type:"radiobtns",
                rbtn:[{
                          Name:"",
                          order:$scope.order
                      }]
                    };
```

How to iterate objct and its rbtn.I mean in the first div we have to iterate the object and inside that first div we need to iterate the rbtn.I have tried like below.

```
<ul>


    <li ng-repeat="radiolbs in radiolabels track by $index">
                        RadioButtons {{$index}}: <input type="text" id="ral_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="$parent.radiolabels[$index].Name"/><br>

                                     <div ng-repeat="r in radiolabels.rbtn track by $index">
                                        Option {{$index}}<input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}"><br>
                                        Option {{$index}}<input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}"><button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
                                    </div>
                </li>
          </ul>
```

Its not working

Comment: No but i got it by changing the "r in radiolabels.rbtn track by $index" as "r in radiolbs.rbtn track by $index"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over the object in the outer loop. This isn't going to work, because your object isn't in an array.

Iterating over an array is what will give you the `$index` variable, otherwise you'll just be iterating over key/value pairs.

You probably want to wrap your outer object inside an array.

```
$scope.radiolabels = [{
  Name: "",
  type: "radiobtns",
  rbtn: [{
    Name: "",
    order: $scope.order
  }]
}];
```

Then your logic for the inner loop can be fixed by asking for the property on the currently iterated object.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="radiolbs in radiolabels track by $index">
    RadioButtons {{$index}}:
    <input type="text" id="ral_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="radiolbs.Name"/><br>

    <div ng-repeat="r in radiolbs.rbtn track by $index">
      Option {{$index}}<input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}"><br>
      Option {{$index}}<input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}">
      <button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ng-init` for this. like:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="radiolbs in radiolabels" ng-init="dataIndex = $index">
   RadioButtons {{dataIndex }}: <input type="text" id="ral_{{dataIndex}}" data-ng-model="$parent.radiolabels[dataIndex ].Name"/><br> 
</ul>
```